# Implementing decoder-only, autoregressive Transformers for OCR

Tags: pytorch, transformer-model

I've been pondering a project recently that involves utilizing my expertise in transformers for an OCR task, specifically detecting and recording text within a game's chat environment. The textual content is primarily a mixture of Japanese, English, digits, and Chinese. It's just a boring side project that will open source if I can successfully detect most of the text.

To give you an overview, I've managed to successfully detect and locate single lines of text using my computer vision skills. However, the challenge arises when I attempt to separate each line of text. To tackle this, I'm contemplating designing a transformer network similar to GPT's architecture (focusing solely on the Decoder, in an autoregressive fashion).

The text in the images appears left-to-right, and I've established the maximum amount of text the image will contain. Consequently, my plan is to transform an image into patches by dividing the width into pieces, specifically `max_seq_len * 2`. This process would result in an image patch sequence with dimensions `[max_s * 2, batch, c]`, which I then intend to feed into the nn.TransformerDecoderLayer.

However, I've hit a stumbling block here, and this brings me to my first question. The nn.TransformerDecoderLayer requires two inputs: tgt and memory. A decoder-only design typically doesn't include an encoder, which would usually be responsible for providing the memory input. I received a suggestion from ChatGPT to circumvent this by directly inputting "None" or "0" to the memory parameter. Would this be a valid approach? Or it's better that I just implement a custom nn.TransformerDecoderLayer that does not require memory input?

Moving forward, my second question is related to the training process. In an autoregressive model, "teacher forcing" is often employed during training by using a "gold token" as input to accelerate the training, in combination with a masking mechanism. In my case, the input comprises patches of image features `(seq, batch, c)`, which is very strange to be directly concatenated with the output text category `(seq, batch, len_category)`. Once again, ChatGPT proposed a solution - using a projection layer for the gold tokens that would allow concatenation with the image features. Does this sound like a feasible solution? My concern is that the target for text classification encompasses over 4k classes, resulting in a large sparse one-hot vector, which seems somewhat unreasonable to concat with image features.

I would be immensely grateful for any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches to address these concerns. I look forward to hearing from you all and greatly appreciate your time.

I use the MobileNetv3 with first 9 layers to extract spatial features, and transform into sequence image patches.
I'm not sure about the correctness of the above mentioned design, so I did not continue.